AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage().ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault() getting httpVerb Error while accessing the blob storage
Application is hosted in Web Farm Scenario. I dont have an option to persist keys for dataprotection() in Database. I am not able to Persist the Key file in blob storage.
I have referred documentation and used these lines of code to store keyfile in blob.
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage('blob-sas-uri')
.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault('keyvault identifier')

When i run the application I am getting the following error.
RequestFailedException: The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.
 ErrorCode: UnsupportedHttpVerb Content:
Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlockBlobRestClient.Upload(long contentLength, Stream body, Nullable<int> timeout, byte[] transactionalContentMD5, string blobContentType, string blobContentEncoding, string blobContentLanguage,...

Am I missing any configuration in Azure portal ?
Thanks in Advance.

My first thought is that there is something wrong with the blob URI. Can you replace the personal values (storage account name etc.) with generic values and post the URI here?

It should be something like this builder.Services.AddAzureClients(cb => {     cb.AddBlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://rithwik.blob.core.windows.net/rithwik/tt.xml")); }); builder.Services.AddDataProtection()     .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("https://rithwik.blob.core.windows.net/rithwik/tt.xml?sp=racwdyti&st=2024-06-27T07:15:41Z&se=2024-06-27T15:15:41Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=fgjj%3D"))     .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri("https://rith98.vault.azure.net/secrets/test"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

@juunas
Here is the blob url I am using
https://.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&restype=container&sp=racwdli&st=2024-06-27T05:01:30Z&se=2024-06-28T13:01:30Z&skoid=&sktid=&skt=2024-06-27T05:01:30Z&ske=2024-06-28T13:01:30Z&sks=b&skv=&sv=&sr=c&sig=

That is a URL for the container, not for a blob. You need to create a blob and create a SAS URL for that. Or do what RithwikBojja suggested in their answer and use Entra ID auth instead.


code to store keyfile in blob.

As an alternative to SAS url , I have given RBAC role Storage Contributor and KeyVault Crypto User role, I used below code and it works for me:
Program.cs:
rith_b.Services.AddAzureClients(ri_cb =>
{
    ri_cb.AddBlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://rithwik.blob.core.windows.net"));
});
rith_b.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("https://rithwik.blob.core.windows.net/rithwik/test.xml"), new DefaultAzureCredential())
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri("https://rith98.vault.azure.net/keys/test"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

Key in KeyVault:

Output:
Blob got created:

Edit:
You can use App registration and create service principal to which you have to give the needed roles:
For Cloud you can use:
using Azure.Identity;
-----
-----
string clntId = "xxx";
string clntSecret = "xxx";
string tenantId = "xxx";
var r_cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clntId, clntSecret);
rith_b.Services.AddAzureClients(ri_cb =>
{
    ri_cb.AddBlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://rithwik.blob.core.windows.net"))
                 .WithCredential(r_cred);
});
rith_b.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("https://stgname.blob.core.windows.net/rithwik/test.xml"), r_cred)
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri("https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/keys/test"), r_cred);
-----
-----


I have used this code and it works fine in local. but when deployed to production I am getting this error
"An error occurred while reading the key ring.
Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information."

For Cloud you can use Client secret, client id, tenant id and app registration. For that service principal you need to give roles. Also refer this

I have edited my answer , under edit section, please check it @roopteja

so this client Id , client secret will be specific to blob and key vault ?
or is it associated to app registration that i am using in this app ?

No App registration is part of Microsoft Entra Id (AD) . Also check this and this for more information on app registration.

Okay, got it. So where will i get this clientId, client secret?
I have checked in Blob storage properties but could not find these values.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
